# Как оптимизировать код под IE 9?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Здравствуйте. У клиента "вдруг" появилась поддержка ИЕ 9, раньше под него заточки не было никакой. Следовательно, писалось все для версий от 10. В FF, Chrome, Opera работает на ура.
Все работает в нормальных браузерах, в ИЕ ошибка:

```
SCRIPT5007: Не удалось получить значение свойства "errorInfo": значением объекта является NULL или он не определен
```

Код сей операции:

```
var query = $.ajax({
    async    : false,
    type     : ajType, //POST
    url      : path,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data     : JSON.stringify( params )
});

query.success( function( result ){
      console.log(result);
      responseErrors( new Array( result ), result.errorInfo, function(){
      auth.user.sessionId = result.sessionId;
      auth.user.login =  loginData.login;
      data.title = "Подтвердите вход";
      updateTemplates( data );  
  });
});
```

`dataType: 'json'` - вот тут немного не понимаю, это указываем тип данных на отдачу или на прием, буду рад, если подскажете, пробовал и json, и html.

По приведенному выше коду: в консольке, которая выводит result внутри промиса success, висит undefined... 
Честно говоря, ума не приложу почему. В нормальных браузерах все работает и только ИЕ не понимает.
С чем это может быть связано, кто знает? )

---

Долго искал хотя бы более-менее адекватное объяснение того почему так происходит в ИЕ9, пробовал сделать с помощью эмуляции, но кроме корявого внешнего вида ничего не изменилось.
Пробовал вешать другие промисы и натолкнулся на .complite, который отработал. Начал копать глубже и...

**Знатоки, внимание - правильный ответ:**

Дело в том, что передавая параметр "result" в функцию, мы не берем в учет остальные возможные параметры (а вот ИЕ берет их в учет) и имеем:

```
complete: function (jqXHR, complete_textStatus) - нужный параметр идет первым и работает
success: function  (data, textStatus, jqXHR) - нужный - третьий и не работает
```

Для себя я решил этот вопрос так:

```
.success( function(){
    result = arguments[2];
    ..... далее по тексту .....
}
```

То есть, получаем массив arguments и его третий элемент приравниваем к result... профит
Спасибо за внимание :)

Comment: А сервер с правильными заголовками ответ отдаёт?

Comment: Вот тут сложный вопрос, на самом деле, потому как я с сервером дела не имею, разрабатываю только front-end. Забираю данные с помощью АПИ от сервера в JSON. Для ИЕ это принципиальный вопрос? Уточню этот момент, должны приходить  с заголовками application/json?

Comment: Это очень просто посмотреть в веб-инспекторе в хроме на вкладке network: https://yadi.sk/i/5c7e43wjc64TD . Из опыта из-за неправильного заголовка часто скрипт отказывается воспринимать json как json.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я затупил чутка. )) Посмотрел, приходит application/json. То есть проблема не в ответе от сервера.

Comment: > ataType: 'json', (вот тут немного не понимаю,

Это тип данных, в котором ожидается получить ответ от сервера.

По вопросу: Баг знакомый и именно в IE9. Некоторые решают проблему за счет эмуляции - директивы X-UA-Compatible. Попробуйте проверить:

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">